неправильное чтение и запись .pgm файла
Я пытался сделать копирование данных файла, но после выполнения программы в файле слишком мало данных (было 1129 Кб, а скопировался только 1). Это работает только в случае, если я запускаю программу и использую форматы .pgm. Если использовать .txt файлы, то вне зависимости от размера, они будут копироваться нормально.
int c = 0;
FILE* dataFile = fopen("data.pgm", "r");
FILE* outFile = fopen("out.pgm", "w");
while ((c = getc(dataFile)) != EOF) 
    putc(c, outFile);
fclose(dataFile);
fclose(outFile);


А если первым байтом в файле будет 0xFF, то сколько прочитается? Используйте методы, предназначенные для бинарных файлов, например - fread

чтение останавливается в случае встречи EOF. EOF = -1

"r" -> "rb", "w" -> "wb"

Похоже, вы работаете в винде?
